# Simple animation program?

Tags: svg, animation, drawing

I am very good with Inkscape, the open source SVG drawing tool. I am looking for something similar in terms of animation - I'd like to do simple things like animate a circle growing, a ball falling, a square moving around, eventually a spline changing shape and the camera's zoom level changing, without the overhead of heavy programs like After Effects or Flash. Do you know of simple to use software that would let me do these sorts of animations, to be embedded in PowerPoint slides for example. Obviously I am not looking for an answer "use PowerPoint"! The program lets me animate moving a whole object, but not the object's properties like color, shape, etc.

Comment: a question of this type might work at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but SU has little respect for software recommendations, and product recommendations. http://superuser.com/help/on-topic  As you can see your question is being closed as off-topic ,  for that reasoning.

Comment: Please see: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2386/migrating-questions-to-software-recommendations-se